# Simple python TypeError: list incides

Tags: python

```
stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']



def addToInventory(inventory,loot):
    for i in loot:
        if loot[i] in inventory.keys:
            inventory.update((loot[i]), +1)
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(loot[i], 1)
    print(inventory)


addToInventory(stuff,dragonLoot)
```

I'm trying to check if an item exists in my stuff list from loot. I get:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to the TypeError that you are seeing, `dragonLoot` is a list and when you iterate over a list, the objects in the list are returned. For example, `"gold coin"` would be returned as one of these objects. You are then attempting to access the item in the list by using the string value as its index value: `dragonLoot["gold coin"]`.  This will not work as you can only access items in a list by their index location: `dragonLoot[0]`. You can access an item in a dictionary by its key such as: `inventory["gold coin"]` which will return the value associated with that key.

I was having trouble with the update method. I would use the key to set the value for the object in the `inventory`:

```
inventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

def addLootToInventory(lootArray):
    for lootObjectKey in lootArray:
        if lootObjectKey in inventory.keys():
            # set the objects new value equal to its current value plus one
            inventory[lootObjectKey] = inventory[lootObjectKey] + 1
        else:
            # the key does not yet exist in the inventory dictionary, create and set to one
            inventory[lootObjectKey] = 1
    print(inventory)

addLootToInventory(dragonLoot)
```

After which, the output was:

```
{'gold coin': 45, 'dagger': 2, 'torch': 6, 'rope': 1, 'arrow': 12, 'ruby': 1}
```

Comment: Sorry. Works! Thank you

Comment: I am iterating over 'loot' and the keys in the 'inventory' object... which is the same thing your code was doing.  Not sure what line you are seeing that error on.

Comment: No problem; happy to help.

Comment: I would definitely say there is some useful information in Terry's answer as well.  I would say that overall you want to use minimal parameters in your functions, use variable names that describe what they contain and also have function names that accurately represent the actions they are performing.  It improves the readability and maintainability of your code which may not be a big deal in this case but it can make all the difference for a large project.

Comment: I modified my answer to be more like Terry's and I altered some variable names.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're introducing a variable you don't want to. You're trying to update your `inventory`, but your `inventory` is the `dragonLoot`?

My suggestion would be to have another variable called `inventory = {}` (EDIT: I didn't realise `stuff` was your main inventory, so that is your main variable), and get rid of your second parameter in your function. You don't need it. You'd do it like so:

```
stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']


def addToInventory(loot):
    for i in loot:
        if i in stuff:
            stuff[i] += 1
        else:
            stuff[i] = 1
    print(stuff)


addToInventory(dragonLoot)
```

I've also cleaned up your code :)

Comment: But addToInventory(inventory,loot) 
(inventory) refers to the 'main inventory' and not the loot.

Comment: @user3599920 Is `stuff` your main inventory?

Comment: @TerryA yup. stuff is main inventory.

Comment: That works! Any idea why my code was messed up? was I using weird functions and messed up variables?

Comment: @user3599920 Yea I told you :P. You were trying to create a new variable for your inventory when you already had one, and so it was only a local variable not global (a global variable is what `stuff` is, since it's defined for everything). You didn't need a local variable at all, all you had to do was update your main variable